# Matrix parser with Lex and Yacc

Tags: parsing, matrix, error-handling, yacc, lex

Hello I'm trying to do a parser for matrix operations.

The lex part is

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "y.tab.h"

%}

%%
[0-9]+              {sscanf (yytext, "%d", &yylval); return (NUM);}
[\+\-*^]            {return (OPERATOR);}
[ \n\t]             {return (yytext[0]);}
.                   ;   
%%
```

And the yacc part is

```
%{

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "lex.yy.c"


    int rows, cols; 
    int matrix[100];
    int k = 0;

%}

%token OPERATOR NUM

%%
matrix: dimensions array    { displayMatrix(rows, cols, matrix);
                            }
      ;

dimensions: NUM NUM { 
                        rows = $1;
                        cols = $2;

                    }
          ;

array: '[' array 
     | NUM array { 
                matrix[k++] = $1;   
           }
     | ']'     
     ;                  
%%


void displayMatrix(int rows, int cols, int array)
{
    printf("\nThe matrix introduced:\n");
    int k = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            printf("%d "), matrix[k++];         
        printf("\n");
    }
}


void yyerror()
{
    printf("Invalid input");
}    

int main()
{
    printf("Introduce the first matrix:\n");
    yyparse();

}
```

What I'm trying to do is to gave the input like this 
no_rows no_cols [ array representing the elements ] 
for example  2 2 [1 2 3 4]

I need to store there values because I need to do operations like + or * on matrix. I don't know exactly how to store these values. I tried something but i run my program it says "invalid input" and I don't have any examples of how I can declare variables and store the values I got form Lex. Also I don't know the dimension of my input array and I don't know how to assign every value.

The commands I used

lex matrix.l

yacc matrix.y

gcc y.tab.c -ll -ly

Thank you!

Comment: You return spaces as tokens (which your grammar does not expect) and skip over `[` and `]` (which you need).  You probably want to swap the actions on the last two flex rules.  You probably also don't want the OPERATOR token or flex rule.

Comment: You were right about that, it worked after I changed. I wasn't even aware that this is how lex and yacc work. Thank you so much. Also a question. First in my main function I need print something then I read a number form the keyboard then I print something once again and after that I call the yyparse() function. Yacc will start to parse from the beginning (also the number that I introduced before) for just explictit everything I give as input after the call of yyparse()? Thank you again!

Comment: lex by default (which you're doing) reads from stdin.  There's no magic rewind or anything, it will just read from stdin in whatever state it is in.  If you've previously read from stdin, then it will read whatever is next.  If stdin is a file or the keyboard or something else, it does not matter -- it just reads stdin.